# Partitions of algebraic curves and maps to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $S$ and $T$ be two disjoint infinite subsets of $X(k)$. Does there exist a morphism $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ and two infinite subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$ such that the preimages of $A$ and $B$ by $f$ lie inside $S$ and $T$ respectively?

Edit: As pointed out by Dragon, this may fail when $k$ is countable, but I would like to know the answer in the general case.

Comment: Yep. Deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No in case $k$ is countable of characteristic zero by a simple diagonal argument. Assume $X$ does not have genus $0$ for simplicity. Number the maps $f_1, f_2, \ldots$. For each $n$ by induction choose $S_n$ and $T_n$ finite disjoint subsets of $X(k)$ such that $f_i$, $i \leq n$ maps an element of $S_n$ and $T_n$ to the same point of $\mathbf{P}^1$. Given $S_n$ and $T_n$ you can choose $S_{n + 1}$ and $T_{n + 1}$ by adding a single point $P$ to $S_n$ and $Q$ to $T_n$ with $P \not = Q$ and $P, Q \not \in S_n \cup T_n$ with $f_{n + 1}(P) = f_{n + 1}(Q)$. This is possible as almost all fibres of $f_{n + 1}$ have cardinality $> 1$. Then take $S = \bigcup S_n$ and $T = \bigcup T_n$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I am still interested in the general case though. I will edit the question.

Comment: The same basic argument works for arbitrary $k$:  the set $\{f_i\}$ has the same cardinality as $k$ and same cardinality as $X(k)$, well-order $\{f_i\}$ by this cardinal, any proper initial segment of $\{f_i\}$ has smaller cardinality and so $P$ and $Q$ can be chosen for the next $f_i$.